# Graph Theory - A sight-seeing Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have come up with a problem that can be modelled in graph theory. Avoiding to reinvent the wheel and wishing to discover new algorithms I have come to ask this question before devising own algorithms.

Let G be a weighted, complete graph. Let S be a subset of the vertices V in G and V0 be an element of V but not of S. A solution is a path that starts at V0 and crosses every vertex in S. An optimal solution is a shortest path crossing all vertices in S.

It can be assumed that |S| will be at most 100 and on average 10.

I am looking for algorithms that find solutions in, considering the complexity of the problem, relatively good time; preferably an algorithm that finds optimal solutions.

Comment: You can't find optimal solutions in a reasonable (polynomial) time -- if you could, you would be able to determine whether a graph has a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is NP-hard.

Comment: Do the graphs you are interested in have additional properties?  For instance, if the graphs have "enough" edges then they must be Hamiltonian, by the Bondy-Chvátal theorem.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon The graph G is a Hamiltonian as it is a complete graph. As implication, the graph S is also a Hamiltonian. I have added some bounds for cardinality of both S; as the cardinality is pretty small algorithms with high time complexity may be considered.